# Should I use ViewModel, safe args or both? If both, how to do this a proper way?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

There're 3 fragments

- AuthFragment - is responsible for the authentication of the user. The authenticated user is stored in the `AuthUser` class. The 'AuthUser`class is passed to the`HomeFragment` via safe args.
- HomeFragment - is responsible for displaying some widgets, whatever, allows to logout (that's why it needs the `AuthUser` - the app gets back to `AuthFragment` on logout) and to go to the `ProfileFragment`. The `ProfileFragment` doesn't need to know anything about authentication, that's why the `HomeFragment` creates a `HomeUser` class which contains the profile information and other things. The `HomeUser` class is passed to the `ProfileFragment` via safe args
- ProfileFragment - displays the `HomeUser` data and allows to get back to the `HomeFragment`

In short, the navigation graph looks like this:

- AuthFragment --(AuthUser)--> HomeFragment
- HomeFragment --> AuthFragment
- HomeFragment --(HomeUser)--> ProfileFragment
- ProfileFragment <--(What here???)-- HomeFragment

The `AuthFragment` uses the `AuthViewModel` and the `AuthRepository` to handle the firebase authentication, but it's not in the scope of this question, so I won't get deeper into it.

Here's the thing, what should I use:

- safe args - the `HomeFragment` would take the `AuthUser` and the `HomeUser` as arguments, and the `AuthUser` would also be passed as an argument to the `ProfileFragment` because the `HomeFragment` needs to have the `AuthUser` valid, so to get back to the `HomeFragment` with a valid `AuthUser` the `ProfileFragment` has to have the valid `AuthUser`.

```java
//AuthFragment to HomeFragment, HomeUser is null
AuthUser authUser = getAuthUser();
var action = AuthFragmentDirections.authToHome(authUser);
NavHostFragment.findNavController(AuthFragment.this).navigate(action);
```

```java
//HomeFragment to ProfileFragment
AuthUser authUser = getAuthUser();
HomeUser homeUser = getHomeUser();
var action = AuthFragmentDirections.homeToProfile(authUser, homeUser);
NavHostFragment.findNavController(HomeFragment.this).navigate(action);
```

```java
//ProfileFragmentto HomeFragment 
AuthUser authUser = getAuthUser();
HomeUser homeUser = getHomeUser();
var action = AuthFragmentDirections.profileToHome(authUser, homeUser);
NavHostFragment.findNavController(ProfileFragment.this).navigate(action);
```

```java
//getting the authUser from arguments
authUser = HomeFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getAuthUser();
```

It sounds confusing, I know... that's why I thought of the `HomeViewModel` class that would contain the `AuthUser` and the `HomeUser`, so let's get into what I thought of

- ViewModel to save the `AuthUser` or/and the `HomeUser` - I've got 2 ideas.

1. The `AuthViewModel` will be also used in the `HomeFragment`, which is not ideal, because `AuthViewModel` contains methods strictly for authorization
2. Create a `HomeViewModel` that will have the `AuthUser`

```java
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public AuthUser authUser;
    public HomeUser homeUser;
}
```

and in the `HomeFragment`

```java
authUser = HomeScreenArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getAuthUser();
homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
homeViewModel.authUser = authUser;
```

My question is, which method is more correct?

1. It doesn't matter if the `ProfileFragment` has access to the `AuthUser` and I can just pass it all around using safe args
2. I should use the `AuthViewModel`, which has authentication methods, in the `HomeFragment`.
3. I should use a combination of safe args and a ViewModel to pass the `AuthUser` to the `HomeFragment` and save it inside a ViewModel